# Notify Child View Controller when super view will disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app I have a root view controller that I added to it's view another view controller's view as a subview. When I navigate (push) from the root to another view controller, the sub view in the root doesn't call the ViewWillDisappear method. How can I let the subview's view controller be notified when it's parent will disappear? Is there a way to do that using KVO ? I want a solution that makes the child view controller completely independent of the parent view controller (no delegate or Notifications to be used). I was wondering if there is a way that i add the child as observer and get notified if the parent will disappear. (note: the child has a property pointing to the parent view controller).

Comment: Are you using addChildViewController: and associated will/didMoveToParentViewController: methods or are you strictly just adding one VC's view as a subview?

Comment: @Acey I'm strictly adding one VC's view as a subview. I'll make sure to try the first option. thanks.

Comment: HAve you tried using container view controller ?

Comment: @GoodSp33d I was about to try it but found out that using the view controller containment procedure a better one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the proper `View Controller Containment` etiquette you should get all of the normal view life cycle calls.

Here are some helpful guides.

http://www.objc.io/issue-1/containment-view-controller.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

It basically boils down to telling a VC its about to be added as a child VC

```
[childVC viewWillMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

adding the view as a subview

```
[self.view addSubview:childVC.view];
```

and adding the VC as a childVC

```
[self addChildViewController:childVC];
```